# How can I query records depending on value existance?

Tags: sql, db2

Assume I have a table with the following entries:

```
ID    VALUE    CATEGORY
-----------------------
 1       10    A
 1       20    S
 2       30    S
 2       10    A
 3       50    A
 4       40    C
 5       60    B
```

How do I write a SQL query so that for each ID if category `S` exists, it should output that record, but if it doesn't exist then it should output the entry which exists.
So in my example I would like to achieve the following result:

```
ID    VALUE    CATEGORY
-----------------------
 1       20    S
 2       30    S
 3       50    A
 4       40    C
 5       60    B
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a more elegant solution :-)

```
SELECT  ID, VALUE, CATEGORY
  FROM  (
      SELECT ID, VALUE, CATEGORY,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID) as SEQ_ID
        FROM MY_TABLE
      ORDER BY ID, CATEGORY DESC
  )
 WHERE SEQ_ID = 1
```

Comment: It should be noted that this only works if `category` is natively sortable.  Otherwise, you're going to have to have some sort of sort-mapping table.  This also doesn't feel like it captures the intent of the described problem, although maybe it's closer to what's really needed.

Answer (score 1):

try,

```
SELECT  ID, VALUE, Category
FROM    tableName
WHERE   Category = 'S'
UNION
SELECT  ID, VALUE, Category
FROM    tableName
WHERE   ID NOT IN
                (
                    SELECT  ID
                    FROM    tableName
                    WHERE   Category = 'S'
                )
ORDER BY ID
```

## [*SQLFiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cc1e8/1)